Calculation the pullback of the metric on $\mathbb R^2$
I try to calculate  the pullback of  the metric on $\mathbb R^2$. I don't know if I got this right, so I write it down for  check.  I've been very impetuous lately, so please let me know if I've made any mistakes.
Consider $\mathbb R^2$ with Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$. Let
$$
\phi: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 
~~~~~~
\phi(x,y)=(3x,2y)
\tag{1}
$$
Then, $\phi$ induce a tangent map, namely
$$
\phi_* : T_{(x,y)}\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow T_{\phi(x,y)} \mathbb R^2
~~~~~~
\phi_*(a\partial_x+b\partial_y) 
= 
(a, b) \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_x \\
\partial_y
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}
$$
Since the global Cartesian coordinates,  $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb R^2$ and $T_{\phi(x,y)} \mathbb R^2$ have same basis $\partial_x, \partial_y$.
Similarly,  $\phi$ induce a pullback, namely
$$
\phi^*: T^*_{\phi(x,y)} \mathbb R^2   \rightarrow   T^*_{(x,y)}\mathbb R^2 
~~~~~~
\phi^*(a dx + b dy) = (a,b) 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
dx \\
dy
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{3}
$$
(3) imply $\phi^*(dx)= \frac{1}{3} dx$ and $\phi^*(dy)= \frac{1}{2} dy$.  Actually, I'm not sure about (3).
Now, give the $\mathbb R^2$ a metric
$$
g(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}  & 0  \\
0 &   \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{4}
$$
Then, I want to calculate $\phi^*g$. First, from (4), there is
$$
g_{11}(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dx\otimes dx  
~~~~
g_{22}(x,y)= \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dy\otimes dy 
~~~~
g_{12}(x,y)=g_{21}(x,y)=0
\tag{5}
$$
Therefore,
$$
(\phi^* g_{11}) (x,y) = \phi^* [g_{11}(\phi(x, y))]= \phi^*[g_{11}(3x, 2y)]
=\phi^* [\frac{1}{1+9x^2+4y^2} dx\otimes dx] = \frac{1}{9(1+9x^2+4y^2)} dx\otimes dx
\tag{6}
$$
Similarly,
$$
(\phi^* g_{22}) (x,y)= \frac{1}{4(1+9x^2+4y^2)} dy\otimes dy
\tag{7}
$$
So,
$$
(\phi^* g)(x,y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{9(1+9x^2+4y^2)}  & 0  \\
0  & \frac{1}{4(1+9x^2+4y^2)}
\end{pmatrix} 
\tag{8}
$$
I want to know if the process to get (8) is right ?

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$. It is $\phi^*(dx) = d(\phi^*(x)) = d(x \circ \phi) = d(3x) = 3dx$ and similar $\phi^*(dy) = 2dy$. Simply calculate
$$\phi^*(g) = \phi^*(f(dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy)) = f\circ\phi  \cdot(\phi^*(dx)\otimes\phi^*(dx) + \phi^*(dy)\otimes\phi^*(dy)) \\
= f\circ \phi\cdot(9dx\otimes dx + 4 dy \otimes dy).$$
So, $\phi^*(g)(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{9}{1+ 9x^2 + 4y^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{4}{1+9x^2 + 4y^2} \end{pmatrix}$.

Could you explain why $\phi^(dx) = d(\phi^(x)) = d(x \circ \phi) = d(3x)$ ?   I can't understand it. Or tell me a reference is enough. Thanks.

Seemly, you treat $x$ as a function.

@EnhaoLan See for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1586606 that pullback and exterior derivative commute.

Thank, I can  accept it.  In fact, the matrices of (3) and (2) are the same, and I remember incorrectly, I remember that they  be inverse. Thanks again.
